# Adding points to pyplot choropeth map

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, choropleth

I have created a choropleth map in python with pyplot on US census data. Now I want to add points to this map denoting the location of towns using longitude and latitude. My code below successfully renders the choropleth but not the points on top

[image]

```
fig1 = px.choropleth(population, locations=population['StateAbbr'], locationmode='USA-states',
 color='per1910',color_continuous_scale='inferno', 
 range_color=(0, .15),scope='usa',labels={'StateAbbr':'per1910'},hover_name='StateAbbr',)

go.Figure(data=go.Scattergeo(
        lon = champs['Lon'],
        lat = champs['Lat'],
        text = champs['School'],
        mode = 'markers',
        marker_color = 'blue',
        ))

fig1.update_layout(title_text = 'Census: 1910 Championships: 1872-1915')
fig1.show()
```

Comment: The first map is defined as fig1, so to add to it we need to do the following. `fig1.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(...)`

Comment: yes was missing fig1.add_trace thank you!

Comment: were you looking for a solution in `matplotlib`? if not, i'll remove this tag to avoid any confusion